# When group action on cartesian product is transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be a group acting transitively on sets $\Omega$ and $\Lambda$. Then there is a natural induced action of $G$ on cartesian product $\Omega \times \Lambda$. I can prove that if $G$ is **finite** this action is transitive if and only if $G = G_{\omega}G_{\lambda}$ for all $\omega\in\Omega, \lambda\in\Lambda$ (here $G_{\omega}$ and $G_{\lambda}$ are stabilisers of $\omega$ and $\lambda$, respectively).

> My question. Is this true, when $G$ is **infinite** group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I believe so. This follows from two statenments.

1. If a group $G$ acts trantively on a set $X$, and $H \le G$, then $H$ acts transitively on $X$ if and only if $G = HG_x$ for all $x \in X$.
2. With your hypotheses, $G$ acts trasitively on $\Omega \times \Lambda$ if and only if $G_\omega$ acts transitively on $\Lambda$ for all (or equivalently some) $\omega \in \Omega$.

I don't really see how finiteness is involved in either of these claims. Which of these are you unsure of, and in which direction?

Comment: thank you very much! Your first observation helped me to understand how to avoid arguments, which using finiteness.